# reCAPTCHA field on page that is loaded through AJAX doesn't load. Suggestions?

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha

Live Examples:

- [Without AJAX](http://utsarotaract.org/inc/email.php)
- [With AJAX (click Email Us link)](http://utsarotaract.org/contact.php)

When I view the source page everything works fine, but when I load through an AJAX request, in the place where the reCAPTCHA **should** be, I see...

```
<noscript>
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfwkccSAAAAALr_z6vDBqkySowo5KIiR0mVM1BX" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
  <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>
```

Obviously, this does nothing unless my user has JS disabled. During this process no errors are thrown.

Viewing the code on the non-AJAX-requested pace, I see...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfwkccSAAAAALr_z6vDBqkySowo5KIiR0mVM1BX"></script>

<noscript>
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfwkccSAAAAALr_z6vDBqkySowo5KIiR0mVM1BX" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
  <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>
```

Note the additional line at the top of the script that addresses users with JS enabled.

So I guess the question is two-fold. WTF is happening and how can I fix it?

I've found some vague mention of this issue, but no decent answers. I found some mention of the reCAPTCHA API using `document.write`, but I don't know if that's valid. If I've overlooked something obvious, please feel free to point it out.

Per request, the AJAX call is...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.get('/inc/email.php', 
           function(data){
                console.log('Get success!');
                $('#email-form').html(data);
                console.log('Get added to #email-form!');
                $('#email-form form').submit( function(){
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",  
                      url: "/inc/email.php",  
                      data: $('#email-form form').serialize(),  
                      success: function() {
                            console.log('Submit success!');
                            $('#email-form').html(data);
                      }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
        }
     );
 });
```

What I've tries so far:

- Rewriting the code to fetch the remote JS file,  replace the document.write() clause with an append to the element I set to a specific ID, then run the modified code inline on the page
- [Displaying reCAPTCHA Without Plugins](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) instead of the [PHP reCAPTCHA library](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php)

Comment: I think you need to include the ajax call and response (use firebug) so that the community can help you.

Comment: I forgot to mention that no errors are thrown through this query. I can include the AJAX call, but I doubt it will add any additional information. It's a simple GET request.

Comment: the interesting thing is the response. if google gives you the wrong code in the first place then something is wrong with your call (api-keys or sth).

Comment: @MartinMüller, how could anything be wrong with my call if the page being viewed independently, without AJAX, loads perfectly?

Comment: I added live example of with and without AJAX at the top of the question.

Comment: ok, I understand now. maybe it is indeed the document.write because the script recaptcha.js is not to be faound in the page after the ajax call. I'm sorry but I can't investigate further now. Maybe in the evening if no answer is found by then.

Comment: Here is a link that was really helpful in solving just this.  Google has addressed many of these issues with reCAPTCHA v2.

http://y-designs.com/blog/google-recaptcha-v2-on-a-dynamic-page/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Explanation:

The reason this breaks when doing it with AJAX, is because [jQuery strips out any `script` tags from your HTML before appending it to the DOM, and evaluates it in the global context](http://old.nabble.com/jQuery.domManip---script-tag-will-be-removed-td24899315s27240.html#a24899512). It does not insert it into the DOM together with the rest of your HTML.

---

### In your code:

The culprit in your code is this line:

```
$('#email-form').html(data);
```

You're taking the raw HTML string recieved from the server, and appending it to the DOM. However, jQuery [first removes the `script` tag from your `data` variable](http://jsfiddle.net/6VShs/), and evaluate that in the global context.

Since the `recaptcha.js` script uses `document.write` to add its stuff to the DOM, it breaks; `document.write` has to run exactly where you want it to output the HTML.

---

### Solutions:

There are 2 possible solutions.

#### Solution #1:

Instead of relying on jQuery completely, you could insert the `script` tag yourself using vanilla JavaScript, which will cause the `document.write` to run where you want it to - right there in the DOM:

```
success: function() {
    var form = $('#email-form')[0],
        script = $('<script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfwkccSAAAAALr_z6vDBqkySowo5KIiR0mVM1BX" />')[0];

    form.appendChild(script);
}
```

Note the `[0]` at the end of those lines. They're used to access the underlying native DOM object, so that we can use the DOM's native `appendChild`.

#### Solution #2:

Instead of loading the data through AJAX, consider putting it in a page of its own, and then just insert an `iframe` into your page:

```
success: function() {
    $('#email-form').html('<iframe src="path/to/reCAPTCHA/page.html" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could **echo** everything in **/inc/email.php** file! You would have to include all the necessary files in advance.